# How can i creating multiple syncronus NSURLConnection request in iPhone

Tags: iphone, json

I have Two url which data display in one viewController

I using json parsing.

I have send request in viewdidload method and getting data into array
same like that i want to send another request at same time and getting data in another array

and showing those data in tableview.

any idea about synchronous NSUrlConnection calling with example.

Answer (score 1):

You will need use something asynchronous.

For example you could go ahead and just wrap these two NSURLConnection calls into a background thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    //NSURLConnection 1... load your first request and put into array
});

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    //NSURLConnection 2... load your second request and put into array
});
```

Comment: hey there no any synchronous way to make NSURLConnection

Comment: Sure there is, but synchronous means the thread is being stopped until there's a response. This means you will have to wait 2x until your arrays are filled.

Answer (score 0):

Use a networking library like AFNetworking.  Will save  you a lot of time and pain using the NSURLConnection and CGD.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445/afnetworking-crash-course

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try this post from link below:

> http://www.isignmeout.com/multiple-nsurlconnections-viewcontroller/